# How to create a method dynamically in ruby with define_method, depending on one instance variable?

Tags: ruby, methods, dynamic

I just don't get the answer to this question. I want to create a method dinamically  with a condition enter in the moment of the instance of the object. I can create the method with other conditions that I tested, but in other circumstances it just doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
class Animal
  def initialize(live, swim)
    @live = live
    @swim = swim
  end
  def live?
    @live
  end
  def swim?
    @swim
  end
end

class Bird < Animal
  def initialize(live, swim, fly)
    super(live, swim)
    @fly = fly
  end

  define_metod(:flying) {puts "flying high"} if @fly
end

Bird.new(true, true, true).flying
```

I tried yet to various other ways to do that. The error is that the method "flying" is not created:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
main.rb:23:in `<main>': undefined method `flying' for #<Bird:0x000056382015df98 @live=true, @swim=true, @fly=true> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: have you tried without `if @fly`?

Comment: I assume `define_metod` was spelled correctly in the code you ran.

Comment: The instance variable `@fly` of `Bird` is never assigned, therefore it evaluates to `nil`, which is falsey, ergo the condition will always be false and the `define_method` will never be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@fly` in `define_method(:flying) {puts "flying high"} if @fly` is a *class instance variable*. It doesn't exist when it's referenced (when the code is parsed), so `nil` is returned, resulting in the `define_method` statement not being executed. The class instance variable `@fly` is unrelated to the instance variables `@fly`, just as `@fly` for one instance is unrelated to `@fly` for another instance.

See @Marcin's answer for how you can achieve your objective.

Comment: Yes, it did exactly what I wanted. Thanks very much you all!

Answer (score 1):

If you'd still like to do that, try like this (simplified example):

```
class A
  def initialize(foo)
    define_singleton_method(:flying) { "flying high" } if foo
  end
end
```

Then:

```
> A.new(true).flying
 => "flying high"
> A.new(false).flying
NoMethodError: undefined method `flying' for #<A:0x0000000589a148 @foo=false>
  from (irb):24
```

This way the `define_singleton_method` is evaluated within the context of specific instance of the class, not the class itself, so you will be able to use any instance's instance variables you wish.